# Is the data in a partition compressed

Tags: oracle, compression, partitioning

This query will give me if a compression has been marked for compression

```
Select *
From All_Tab_Partitions
```

It came up in discussion that a Partition marked for compression can actually contain uncompressed data if it is loaded with FAST_LOAD.

I want to only issue compression commands for uncompressed partitions.

How can I find out if the data inside a partition is compressed or not?

Answer (score 1):

Basic compression may be *enabled* on a partition but it is only *used* if data was created from a direct-path insert. Direct-path inserts are not the default type of insert; they usually require extra code, such as a hint like `/*+ APPEND */`, or setting an option in a third-party data loading application. And you may need to make some changes to objects to enable direct-path writes, such as disabling triggers and some foreign keys. So it's not always possible or even desirable to enable direct-path inserts that can take advantage of basic compression.

Use sampling and the function
[DBMS_COMPRESSION.GET_COMPRESSION_TYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/d_compress.htm#ARPLS72894) to estimate the percent of rows
compressed per partition.

**Schema**

```
create table compression_test
(
  a number,
  b varchar2(100)
) partition by range(a)
(
  partition p_all_compressed values less than (2) compress,
  partition p_none_compressed values less than (3) compress,
  partition p_half_compressed values less than (4) compress
);

insert /*+ append */ into compression_test partition (p_all_compressed)
select 1, '0123456789' from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;
insert into compression_test partition (p_none_compressed)
select 2, '0123456789' from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;
insert /*+ append */ into compression_test partition (p_half_compressed)
select 3, '0123456789' from dual connect by level <= 50000;
commit;
insert into compression_test partition (p_half_compressed)
select 3, '0123456789' from dual connect by level <= 50000;
commit;
```

**Estimate Code**

```
--Find percent compressed from sampling each partition.
declare
  v_percent_compressed number;
begin
  --Loop through partitions.
  for partitions in
  (
    select table_owner, table_name, partition_name
    from dba_tab_partitions
    --Enter owner and table_name here.
    where table_owner = user
      and table_name = 'COMPRESSION_TEST'
  ) loop
    --Dynamic SQL to sample a partition and test for compression.
    execute immediate '
      select
        round(sum(is_compressed)/count(is_compressed) * 100) percent_compressed
      from
      (
        --Compression status of sampled rows.
        --
        --Numbers are based on constants from:
        --docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17602/d_compress.htm
        --Assumption: Only basic compression is used.
        --Assumption: Partitions are large enough for 0.1% sample size.
        select
          case dbms_compression.get_compression_type(
              user,
              '''||partitions.table_name||''',
              rowid,
              '''||partitions.partition_name||'''
            )
            when 4096 then 1
            when 1 then 0
          end is_compressed
        from '||partitions.table_owner||'.'||partitions.table_name||'
        partition ('||partitions.partition_name||') sample (0.1)
      )
    ' into v_percent_compressed;

    dbms_output.put_line(rpad(partitions.partition_name||':', 31, ' ')||
      lpad(v_percent_compressed, 3, ' '));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

**Sample Output**

```
P_ALL_COMPRESSED:              100
P_HALF_COMPRESSED:              55
P_NONE_COMPRESSED:               0
```